# Is it possible to serialize an object to a stream while simultaneously reading that stream and deserializing it?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Background: I'm creating a copy of an object by serializing/deserializing it. This may be an X/Y problem, but I've tried alternative copy approaches and they don't work for me.

[Newtonsoft.Json says](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage) it is a good idea to reduce memory usage of serialization by serializing or deserializing using streams. It says that this is:

> especially important when working with JSON documents greater than 85kb in size to avoid the JSON string ending up in the large object heap.

My objects can be 1-2MB in size so this seems applicable.

Is it possible for a serializer to serialize an object to a stream which is simultaneously deserialized to a clone object, therefore avoiding the allocation of a potentially very large string? I know you can serialise to a stream, flush the writer and seek to 0, but isn't that just doing *all* the writing first and then *all* the reading after?

Or is this all pointless since we've already got a large object in-memory anyway?

Comment: Indeed it is possible - the doc you linked shows just that - someone on server side of API writes response to the stream and code reading the JSON reads it from the stream potentially at the same time... Now there is no stream in the Framework that gives you such behavior immediately for in-process communication, but creating one that properly supports read and write at the same time with relatively small buffer is doable (would need to make everything properly async as you need to read and write from two parallel tasks/threads)...

Comment: Whether this effort worth is a personal choice... I'd just ignore all that till you actually have that as a problem confirmed by perf measurements and corresponding goals... Just serialize through an MemoryStream and ignore LOH issues.

Comment: Stream in .net is ambiguous - it isn't entirely clear whether a stream is duplex or not, and what you're asking depends on that. Things like NetworkStream *are* duplex (which means inout and output are entirely independent, essentially two separate streams); memorystream, filestream, etc: are *absolutely not* duplex. What you are asking requires a duplex stream, or two separate streams.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't believe OP is looking for a duplex stream (or such steam would be helpful for cloning)... Actually, come to think of it, it could be XY-problem - if OP is looking for high-performance cloning of objects than doing via JSON serialization is quite sub-optimal choice and direct copy with libraries (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713556/copy-object-to-object-with-automapper) or manual reflection-based code would be better by avoiding all intermediate conversions.